# App opens launch screen but crashes (On iOS Device)

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

I am having a bit of trouble trying to test my app on a physical device. Every time I go and test my app through `TestFlight` it just opens the `LaunchScreen` for a split second then crashes. This is strange because it works perfectly in the simulator.

I'm not using `StoryBoards` and I've read around, and people said to get rid of all of the main `Storyboard` references in `info.plist` and the build settings. I have done so and it still isn't working.

I have attached screenshots below:

**Info.plist**

[image]

**Build Settings**

[image]

Also, I have a feeling it could be something to do with my `AppDelegate`, due to me trying to do everything programatically.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate 
{
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        let navController = UINavigationController()
        let mainViewController = ViewController(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)

        // NavigationBar/Title colour
        navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:3/255, green:60/255, blue:115/255, alpha:1);


        // Push the viewcontroller onto the navigation controller
        navController.pushViewController(mainViewController, animated:false)

        self.window!.rootViewController = navController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) 
    {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) 
    {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) 
    {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) 
    {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) 
    {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift - ViewDidLoad()**

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "MyApp"
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 40/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        // container
        mainContainer = UIView()

        // button
        btn_Schedule = UIButton()
        btn_Career = UIButton()
        btn_Social = UIButton()
        btn_Feedback = UIButton()
        btn_Details = UIButton()

        // Label
        lbl_Copywrite = UILabel()

        // Horizontal Dividing lines
        dividingLineTop = UIView()
        dividingLineBottom = UIView()

        // images
        img_Schedule = UIImage()
        img_Career = UIImage()
        img_Social = UIImage()
        img_Feedback = UIImage()
        img_Details = UIImage()

        img_Schedule = UIImage(named:"imgschedule.PNG")
        img_Career = UIImage(named:"imgcareer.PNG")
        img_Social = UIImage(named:"imgsocial.PNG")
        img_Feedback = UIImage(named:"contact.PNG")
        img_Details = UIImage(named:"imgdetails.PNG")

        // set up button clicks
        btn_Schedule.addTarget(self, action:"onMyScheduleButton_Clicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        btn_Career.addTarget(self, action:"onMyCareerButton_Clicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        btn_Social.addTarget(self, action:"onMySocialButton_Clicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        btn_Feedback.addTarget(self, action:"onFeedbackButton_Clicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        btn_Details.addTarget(self, action:"onMyDetailsButton_Clicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue
        {
            displayMenuInLandscapeMode()
        }
        else 
        {
            if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
            {
                displayMenuInLandscapeMode()
            }
            else
            {
                displayMenuInPortraitMode()
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: you ran it on a device before sending it to test flight? what is the crash log message and stack trace?

Comment: I don't have a physical mac so I'm using Macincloud. Im unable to test on devices without using Testflight and I havent been able to get any crash data. Unless you can access it through XCode? Im new to XCode and iOS Development.

Comment: Why you don't run it in your device using Xcode? to see the crash log?

Comment: you might need to add some crash logging code / service to get more details. unless test flight keeps crash logs for you, not sure

Comment: Because im using a virtual mac desktop on my windows machine so I can't connect my device to that virtual mac.

Comment: Could this be a memory issue?

Comment: I compiled your code on xCode on an iMac and ran it on a real iPhone5 and it worked ok. I commented out all of viewDidLoad below the statement with `mainContainer`. I used your appDelegate code exactly. I created a new single-view application project in xCode (which creates a storyboard) and just deleted the VC from the storyboard, left storyboard and plist there, and it worked. Keep trying, cannot be far off!

Comment: @emrys57 I'll give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Which device and iOS version? Did you try with other iOS version?

Comment: I have tried on a number of different devices and the same thing happens, launch screen opens for a slit second then it just closes.

Comment: Then where is the crash log?

Comment: Im using a remote Mac so im unable to retrieve the crash logs due to not being able to connect my device to the machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crashes on startup when I add image to button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572800/app-crashes-on-startup-when-i-add-image-to-button)

Comment: Any updates? How do you fix this issue? I'm facing the same issue without storyboard too. It seems that there are UIWindow without rootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's ridiculous but remove the `navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]`. 
I was having the same issue. Everything works locally but not on TestFlight.

You can change the colour of the title by setting the `navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black`